Update to cleveref firstaid adds space after tcolorbox documentation commands
After updating to the Nov 2024 LaTeX release, loading cleveref causes a space to be placed after tcolorbox's documentation commands.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[documentation]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
    
\section{Global options}

\begin{docCommand}{foomakedocSubKey}{\marg{name}\marg{key path}}
Creates a new environment \meta{name} based on docKey for the
documentation of keys with the given \meta{key path}.
\end{docCommand}
\begin{docKey}[foo]{footitle}{=\meta{text}}{no default, initially empty}
Creates a heading line with \meta{text} as content.
\end{docKey}

\end{document}


What's causing this? If the section is removed, the spaces go away. I tried the fix from Ulrike's answer to another problem with the cleveref firstaid but the issue is still there, so I think this is a different issue.
P.S. I am aware cleveref is not actively maintained, so the kernel patching is likely to cause issues over time. I will personally move to zref-clever but the package is still quite popular for users.

grumpf. I will look ...

@UlrikeFischer Thanks

oh, well a simple spurious space - you should have asked egreg ;-)

There is a spurious space in the hook. You can fix that for now by removing the hook and reinserting a corrected version:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[documentation]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\RemoveFromHook{label}[firstaid/cleveref]
\makeatletter
\AddToHook{label}[firstaid/cleveref]
         {\ifx
           \@currentcounter\@empty
          \else
           \firstaid@cref@updatelabeldata{\@currentcounter}%<--- was missing
          \fi} 
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Global options}

\begin{docCommand}{foomakedocSubKey}{\marg{name}\marg{key path}}
Creates a new environment \meta{name} based on docKey for the
documentation of keys with the given \meta{key path}.
\end{docCommand}

\begin{docKey}[foo]{footitle}{=\meta{text}}{no default, initially empty}
Creates a heading line with \meta{text} as content.
\end{docKey}


\end{document}

